# Functions of two variables finding maxima

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find maximize $9x+4y$ subject to the condition $|3x|+|2y|\le 1$. In this problem, have to use the Lagrange multiplier method, but the function mod $3x+\operatorname{mod} 2y$ is not differentiable, which is why I am having difficulties. Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It is a linear programming problem. Draw the feasible region (it is a parallelogram), find the corner points and evaluate the objective function at the corner points.

Comment: you are welcome. good luck